# Error in VirtualBox while importing a .ova file

Tags: virtualbox

Today I was creating a virtual machine which would run Kali linux. Upon importing the Kali linux's .ova file I got an error:

```
Failed to import appliance /home/<MyUserName>/Downloads/kali-linux-2018.2-vbox-amd64/kali-linux-2018.2-vbox-amd64.ova.
```

Details:

```
Seeking within the archive failed (VERR_TAR_UNEXPECTED_EOS).

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: 
ApplianceWrap
Interface: 
IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}
```

Can somebody please help me solve this error? I tried hard to find a solution but just couldn't.

Comment: did you tried a download of your ova, looks like invalid file format maybe. It could also be that you need to upgrade virtual box, or  extract the disk image from the ova and create the VM manually.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your virtual box to the latest version. Worked for me.