# Why can't I import the Appliance OVA into Virtualbox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I was setting up a CyberOps Workstation virtual machine but I get the following error.

vbox:Machine element in OVF contains a medium attachment for the disk image but the OVF describes no such image.

Result Code:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:
ApplianceWrap
Interface:
IAppliance {86a98347-7619-41aa-aece-b21ac5c1a7e6}

While researching about the problem people recommended changing the network adapter but how do I even get to that window if it doesn't even import.

[image]

PS: I have looked at the dup here: [Error in VirtualBox while importing a .ova file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449305/error-in-virtualbox-while-importing-a-ova-file). It has no solution. I have the latest version of Virtual Box.

Comment: I think this is a windows / virtualbox question. It seems (let me know if I am wrong), that you are trying to import the image and failing... did you check/redownload the image? Perhaps it is corrupt?

Comment: Yes you are right I'll edit it and I have tried redownloading the image and it worked for my friends I don't know why I'm getting this error. Is an ova file meant for VM Ware?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-import-vm.html), you can import ova. The link you linked to says update virtualbox, but I am assuming you are running a recent version.

Comment: @number9 yes I checked it again an its up to date what else could cause this error

Comment: I got the exact same error. The cause was insufficient storage space, and the solution to expand the storage space.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today.  I believe it was due to running out of drive space on the drive I was trying to install the VM on.  I tried a different drive on another drive and it installed normally.

If this is the case, it should have an error message specifically stating that this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Deselect "Import hard drives as VDI" option

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to rename VMDK file, back to the orginal one, as the download process added redundant characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me (Windows 11 System):

1. Check for updates on VirtualBox via **File > Check for Updates**.
2. Ensure you have enough space for where you are importing the OVA file. If external drive, **NTFS** filesystem works.
3. Enable NAT networking in the network preferences via **File > Preferences > Network > Green Plus** (`NatNetwork` - Make sure it is checked under the Active tab).

(Tested on 32 GB USB)